# Zend_Form_Element requires each element to have a name

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I'm trying to create a form in ZF 1.Here's my form class

```
class Application_Form_Album extends Zend_Form
{

    public function init()
    {
        $this->setName('album');

        #artist 
        $artist = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('artist');
        $artist->setLabel('Artist')->setRequired(true)->addValidator('NotEmpty');

        #title
        $title = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('title');
        $title->setLabel('Title')->setRequired(true)->addValidator('NotEmpty');

        #submit
        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit();
        $submit->setAttribute('id','submitbutton');

        $this->addElements(array($artist,$title,$submit));
    }


}
```

and my controller action

```
public function addAction()
 {
     $form = new Application_Form_Album();
     $form->submit->setLabel('Add');
     $this->view->form = $form;
 }
```

and my add.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->form;?>
```

But I'm getting this error.

```
Message: Zend_Form_Element requires each element to have a name
```

Not sure what I missed.Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give a `name` for each form element. Missing name of submit. Zend Form generate `id` and `name` html tags from given name
For example:

```
$submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submitbutton');
```

And remove

```
$submit->setAttribute('id','submitbutton');
```

line.

Comment: Thank you.It's working now.But I get a blank page when I remove `addElements()`

Comment: I'm sorry, you should remove  `$submit->setAttribute('id','submitbutton');` line. Thanks.

Comment: Edited the changes in your answer @HaykManasyan